# ASP.NET Can't access pages with role permissions on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, iis, authentication

I've created an application with the default login system and created a folder "Client" that only administrators should have access to.  I put my site on IIS and fixed some login errors in which I needed to grant the NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE user permission.

Now I'm dealing with this next error, which I've encountered before, but I'm not sure how to deal with it.  It appears that I can login, but when I try to navigate to the Client folder, I get this error.

```
Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file 
required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below 
and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Providers, 
Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its 
dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I did some searching and it looked like some people said to:

"Use this NuGet command to install your DLL automatically: 
    Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.Core"

I ran that command, and now not only does the Client folder give me that error, every page gives me that error.

Here's my config:

```
<configuration>
<configSections>
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
<!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
</configSections>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-ClientInfo-20140530090429;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-ClientInfo-20140530090429.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="clientConnection" connectionString="Data Source=EDITOR1;Initial Catalog=info;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="CLIENT" connectionString="Data Source=EDITOR1;Initial Catalog=clientInformation;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.DirectoryServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
    <add assembly="System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
  </assemblies>
 </compilation>
 <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
 <pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
  </namespaces>
  <controls>
    <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />
  </controls>
  </pages>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Authenticate.aspx" timeout="2880" />
 </authentication>
 <profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
  </profile>
  <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
 </membership>
 <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <add connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </providers>
  </roleManager>
  <!--
        If you are deploying to a cloud environment that has multiple web server instances,
        you should change session state mode from "InProc" to "Custom". In addition,
        change the connection string named "DefaultConnection" to connect to an instance
        of SQL Server (including SQL Azure and SQL  Compact) instead of to SQL Server Express.
  -->
 <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
  </providers>
  </sessionState>
 <identity impersonate="false" />
</system.web>
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
</entityFramework>
<appSettings>
<add key="DirectoryPath" value="LDAP://srv-sbs.fs.local/dc=fs,dc=local" />
<add key="DirectoryDomain" value="SRV-SBS.fs.local" />
</appSettings>
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `<ConfigSections>` doesn't have entry for System.Web.Providers. Insert it in the same way you've done for entityframework. Like:

Insert the providers written below:

```
<providers>
    <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
```

Into some tag like `<Entity></Entity>.`

Then define it in the section on top like:

<`ConfigSections>
<section name="Entity"  type="System.Web.Providers" ______________/>
</ConfigSections>`

Completely fill it in the same way as done for entity framework.

Check the exact public key token for the DLL using command sn -T on visual studio command prompt and insert entry into ConfigSections.

The better option is: there is a small exe application EnterpriseLibray.Config..(Don't know the complete name. Google it..). If you run this application for assemblies it automatically insert the required entries related to the dll into the desired places of web.config.